# Is it OK to add tags for little used commercial software?

Tags: discussion, tags

I want to ask a question about wyBuild, so I did a search and discovered there are no tags for it. There are 14 existing questions with "wyBuild" that could potentially be tagged, and 7 questions with "wyUpdate", which could be created as a tag synonym. Three of these questions are the same (they mention both words), and some are only mentioning it to say that's not the solution they want, or that they've already considered and dismissed it.

1. Is it OK for me to create [wybuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wybuild) and its synonym [wyupdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wyupdate)?
2. If so, should the old questions that are about wyBuild be retagged if they currently have fewer than 5 tags?
3. In general, how do you know if it's appropriate to create a new tag for little used software?